# How to wrap sol to wsol using JS

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I have the transaction instruction which only required the wrap sol to proceed further like depositing it in another vault so, I have to convert the sol to wrapsol first and then proceed with that transaction

Answer (score 1):

```
const wrapSol = async (
  connection: Connection,
  wallet: any,
  depositAmount: number,
) => {
  let createWrapSolAccountTransaction = new Transaction()
  const wrapSolAccount = Keypair.generate()
  const accountRentExempt = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(AccountLayout.span)
  createWrapSolAccountTransaction.add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: wrapSolAccount.publicKey,
      lamports: depositAmount * (10 ** 9) + accountRentExempt * 3,
      space: AccountLayout.span,
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
  )
  createWrapSolAccountTransaction.add(
    Token.createInitAccountInstruction(
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      NATIVE_MINT,
      wrapSolAccount.publicKey,
      wallet.publicKey,
    )
  )
  let signature: any = await wallet.sendTransaction(
    createWrapSolAccountTransaction,
    connection,
    {signers: [wrapSolAccount] }
  )

  await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed')

  let balance = await connection.getTokenAccountBalance(wrapSolAccount.publicKey);

  console.log("+ User's wrapSol account: ", wrapSolAccount.publicKey.toBase58(), balance.value.uiAmountString)
  return {
    address: wrapSolAccount.publicKey,
    balance: balance.value.uiAmountString,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example in Solana Cookbook: https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#add-balance